# A guy talks his way out of jail with magic

Tags: story-identification

So I was suggested a book that was really good. She can't remember the title, but supposedly the opening scene has the main character in jail, and he talks his way out of jail by talking to nails and the door falls apart.

Supposedly it also has Magic or Magician in the title. And has a red cover.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm certain it's "The Spirit Thief" from the Eli Monpress series by Rachel Aaron. Here is the beginning of the first novel: [Spirit thief sample](http://www.rachelaaron.net/thespiritthief-sample.php).

> “Indecision is the bane of all hardwoods.” Eli shook his head. “Come on, it doesn’t have to be forever. Just give it a try.”
>
> The door clanged softly against its frame, gathering its resolve as Eli made encouraging gestures. Then, with a loud bang, the nails popped like corks, and the boards clattered to the ground with a long, relieved sigh.

Comment: Yet another reason to LOVE Jules in _Pulp Fiction_: "My name's Pitt, and your a-- ain't talkin' your way outta this s--t."

Answer (score 3):

She may be thinking of the portion of the Xanth series starring the [Magician Dor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magician_Dor) as the protagonist - he appears as the main character in three of the Xanth novels, *Castle Roogna, Centaur Aisle, and Night Mare*, and his talent is the ability to communicate with inanimate objects. The titles of the books don't include the word Magician, but the term 'Magician' is often used to describe characters in the books.